# Get result of a JS file directly? (sorta AJAX related)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, excel, url

As I have known AJAX in the past, it has gone something like this: a server side language (in my case PHP) file generates xHTML has JS attached. The JS queries another file, with parameters set in `GET` or `POST`. This queried file's entire output is returned to the JS, which in turn makes a change on the original xHTML.

Now, I'm trying to do something which is sorta related to those same techniques. I want to query URLs from Excel, like

`www.example.com/distance?to=FTW&from=ACR`

and the entire return value would be something like

`2231`

If I just query the JS file directly, it won't get run.

If I set up an html page, it's trivial to have it display nothing but that number, but the return value of the query contains a bunch of tags.

How else can I do this? What if I had a PHP file, that runs the JS, then returns its value?

The business logic of getting the number has to be in javascript.

Comment: May I ask WHY it has to be in JS? It'd make more sense using cURL to get the data, then put it into the output from the PHP. Otherwise, just run the javascript with the onload event in the body, then document.write() the entire contents. Then you'll have nothing output from the PHP, and the whole page would be the values returned from the other script. I'd suggest not using JS though... Some people, believe it or not, have it turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a callback function to handle the value

in your main file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */
   function valcallback(val){
     // so something with val
   }
/* ]]> */</script>
```

in your JS file, return:

```
valcallback(2231);
```

and it'll run like javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The Excel request side can be handled with this VBA code.

```
Sub GetDistance()

Dim objXML As Object
Dim strData As String
Dim strResponse As String

 strData = "to=FTW&from=ACR"
 Set objXML = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

 objXML.Open "POST", "www.example.com/distance?" & strData, False
 objXML.Send
 strResponse = objXML.responsetext
 MsgBox strResponse

End Sub
```

Comment: how do I take this VBA code and use it to determine the value of a cell?

Comment: Sample code to loop through cells A1 to A10 on Sheet1,
pick up the cell values and report them in a message box.

Sub GetData()
Dim strOutput As String
Dim strData As String
 Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Select
 For i = 0 To 9
  strData = CStr(ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value)
  strOutput = strOutput & vbCr & vbLf & strData
 Next i
 MsgBox strOutput
End Sub